# how to insert text as icon on map

Tags: python, python-3.x, folium

insert text as icon on map i have attached error image with it
This code mark latitude longitude on map but i have to insert text on each.
I am using folium to insert the symbol
what should i edit to make text visible
[error code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHXUJ.png)

```
import folium
import branca
from folium import plugins
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\VinitJ\Documents\lat_long.csv")
df.head()
df
legend_html ="""
     <table width = 100%,  style="font-size: 20px;">

    <tr><td style="color:blue">Less than equal to 50&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"
                  style="color:blue"></td>

     <td style="color:green">between 50 to 100&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"
                  style="color:green"></td>
    <td style="color:yellow">between 100 to 200&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"
                  style="color:yellow"></td>
     <td style="color:orange">above 200&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"
                  style="color:red"></td>


     </table>
     """
folium.Element(legend_html)
m = folium.Map([39.4133, -105.7567], zoom_start=5,width = 5000, height = 2500, top = 20)

m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(legend_html))



#for index, row in df.iterrows():
#    folium.Marker([row['lat'], row['lon']], 
#                  #popup=row['City','COUNTRY'],
#                  icon=folium.Icon(icon='')
#                 ).add_to(m)

#m.save('map4.html')
#m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(legend_html))
#df.rename(columns={'Peering DB code':'PeeringDBcode','SITE CODE':'SITECODE','SITE ADDRESS':'SITEADDRESS','Site Type':'SiteType','IP PoP Status':'IPPoPStatus','IP SLA':'IPSLA','In Service Date':'InServiceDate'},inplace =True)

def fancy_html(row):
    i = row


    city = df['city'].iloc[i]
    Value = df['value'].iloc[i]                                           



    left_col_colour = "#2A799C"
    right_col_colour = "#C5DCE7"

    html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
            <h4 style="margin-bottom:0"; width="300px">{}</h4>""".format(city) + """
            </head>
                <table style="height: 126px; width: 300px;">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td style="background-color: """+ left_col_colour +""";"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Top PLot</span></td>
            <td style="width: 200px;background-color: """+ right_col_colour +""";">{}</td>""".format(city) + """
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="background-color: """+ left_col_colour +""";"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Value</span></td>
            <td style="width: 200px;background-color: """+ right_col_colour +""";">{}</td>""".format(Value) + """
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </html>
            """
    return html
#location = df['lat'].mean(), df['lon'].mean()
#m = folium.Map(location=location,zoom_start=15,min_zoom=5)

#for i in range(0,len(df)):
#    html = fancy_html(i)
# 
#    iframe = branca.element.IFrame(html=html,width=400,height=300)
#    popup = folium.Popup(iframe,parse_html=True)
#    
#    folium.Marker([df['Latitude'].iloc[i],df['Longitude'].iloc[i]],
#                  popup=popup,icon=folium.Icon(color=color, icon='info-sign')).add_to(m)
#

text =df['value']
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    num_of_casualties = df['value'].iloc[i]
    if num_of_casualties <= 50:
        color = 'blue'
    elif num_of_casualties <= 100:
        color = 'green'
    elif num_of_casualties <= 200:
        color = 'yellow'
    else:
        color = 'red'

    html = fancy_html(i)

    iframe = branca.element.IFrame(html=html,width=400,height=200)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe,parse_html=True)

#folium.map.Marker(
#[df['lat'].iloc[i],df['lon'].iloc[i]],
#icon=DivIcon(
#        icon_size=(150,36),
#        icon_anchor=(0,0),
#         html='<div style="font-size: 24pt">%s</div>' % text,
#         )
#       .add_to(m) 




    folium.CircleMarker([df['lat'].iloc[i],df['lon'].iloc[i]],radius=12,color=color,
                        popup=popup,fill_color=color).add_to(m)
#m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(legend_html))




m.save('map21.html')
```

This code mark latitude longitude on map but i have to insert text on each.
I am using folium to insert the symbol
what should i edit to make text visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

folium has a `DivIcon` class you could use. You can pass any html which will be used to create the marker. For example:

```
div = folium.DivIcon(html=(
    '<svg height="100" width="100">'
    '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />'
    '<text x="30" y="50" fill="black">9000</text>'
    '</svg>'
))
folium.Marker((0, 0), icon=div).add_to(m)
```